# Group by specific linked column to the other column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with 4 features i.e. user_id, comment_id, reply_to_id and comment_text. My question is to group-by the reply_id which is linked to the comment_id. The main purpose of this logic is to identify the branch comments of all the root comments. By this way, I can identify all the root comments and branch comments. (I welcome any suggestion to tackle this issue and if you have any other suggestion to approach this type of problem)

Table:

```
user_id |  comment_id | reply_to_id | comment_text
123     | 8           |             | How are you?
456     | 9           |             | May I help you?
1256    | 10          | 8           | I am good. What about you? 
6543    | 11          |             | Weather is not good today
234     | 12          | 9           | Thank you, I will manage
```

I want all comment_id and reply_to_id to be grouped. The output should look like:

```
user_id |  comment_id | reply_to_id | comment_text
123     | 8           |             | How are you?
1256    | 10          | 8           | I am good. What about you? 
456     | 9           |             | May I help you?
234     | 12          | 9           | Thank you, I will manage
6543    | 11          |             | Weather is not good today
```

Comment: will each 'comment_id' will have only one 'reply_to_id'? in other words, for example 8 will appear only one in  'comment_id' & only once in 'reply_to_id'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Setup*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': {0: 123, 1: 456, 2: 1256, 3: 6543, 4: 234},
 'comment_id': {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 10, 3: 11, 4: 12},
 'reply_to_id': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '8', 3: '', 4: '9'},
 'comment_text': {0: ' How are you?',
  1: ' May I help you?',
  2: ' I am good. What about you? ',
  3: ' Weather is not good today',
  4: ' Thank you, I will manage'}})
```

You can probably try something like this using a temp column for sorting:

```
(
    df.assign(sort_key=df.apply(lambda x: int(x.comment_id) if x.reply_to_id=='' else int(x.reply_to_id), axis=1))
    .sort_values(by='sort_key')
    .drop('sort_key', 1)
)

    user_id comment_id  reply_to_id comment_text
0   123     8                       How are you?
2   1256    10          8           I am good. What about you?
1   456     9                       May I help you?
4   234     12          9           Thank you, I will manage
3   6543    11                      Weather is not good today
```

Comment: when i try this, i get the error "AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'reply_to_id'", 'occurred at index 0')". Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you try using the dataframe from my answer? it's most likely the reply_to_id column in your dataframe has trailing spaces

Comment: Please consider upvote and accept it as the answer if it works for you. @mohanys